# Creating plugins on dspace

Tags: dspace

I'm doing a repository implementation using dspace.
I need to develop a feature that is not present and I need this resource to be a plugin, but I can not find anything to help me. If anyone can help, I'll be grateful.

Comment: What version of DSpace do you plan to use?  DSpace 6 is the current version.  What is the nature of the plugin that you plan to create?  DSpace has mechanisms for add custom data crosswalks, data curation tasks, integration with identifier/authority systems.

Comment: I plan to use version 6. The plugin I want to do should allow content reporting.

Comment: See https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/Release+Notes . The "REST Based Quality Control Reports" or the "Extensible administrative control panel" might provide a starting point for you.

Comment: REST works for what I want, but I find nothing about creating my own class.